# Como pegar os itens dentro de um object(stdClass) no PHP?

Tags: php, objetos, stdclass

Estou fazendo importação com PHP por uma api, e não sei como pegar os valores do `object(stdClass)` que estão dentro do `$fotos`. Tentei das 2 maneiras abaixo, mas acredito que esteja errado:

```
foreach($fotos as $f){
var_dump($f);
}

foreach($fotos->id as $f){
var_dump($f);
}
```

Preciso pegar os valor de id, description e 1024x1024

```
object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
    ["id"]=> string(6) "288848"
    ["description"]=> string(8) "Banheiro"
    ["1024x1024"]=> string(100) "https://s3.amazonaws.com/linkapi/images/properties/large/288848.jpeg?1587723622"
}
```

Atualização:
Assim funcionou para o id e description, mas o 1024x1024  dá erro, acho q por ser numero:

```
foreach($fotos as $f){
            foreach($f as $foto){
                var_dump($foto->description);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Para `stdClass` basta usar chaves/chavetas (curly bracket), assim:

```
$foo->{'1024x1024'}
```

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array('1024x1024' => 'foo');

var_dump($obj->{'1024x1024'});
```

Exemplo online: https://repl.it/@inphinit/stdclass-php

E também pode passar uma variável, acaso queira obter um valor de uma chave:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) [
  'foo-bar' => 'baz',
  'boo-baz' => '1000'
];

$busca = 'foo-bar';

var_dump($obj->{$busca});
```

E acaso o valor não exista você pode usar `isset()` ou `??` (null coalescing, se for PHP7+) para checar se o valor existe, exemplos:

```
$busca = 'foo-bar';

echo isset($obj->{$busca}) ? $obj->{$busca} : 'não encontrado';
```

Com `??` (null coalescing)

```
$busca = 'foo-bar';

echo $obj->{$busca} ?? 'não encontrado';
```

Também é possível usar **dentro de strings** geradas a partir de [aspas duplas (**Double quoted**)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), exemplo:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) [
    'foo' => 'Valor de bar',
    'foo-bar' => 'Valor de foo-bar',
    '123-456' => 'Valor de 123-456',
    '123x456' => 'Valor de 123x456',
    '0a' => 'Valor de 0a'
];

echo "
{$obj->foo}
{$obj->{'foo-bar'}}
{$obj->{'123-456'}}
{$obj->{'123x456'}}
{$obj->{'0a'}}
";
```

Ou strings com a sintaxe [Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
echo <<<EOT
{$obj->foo}
{$obj->{'foo-bar'}}
{$obj->{'123-456'}}
{$obj->{'123x456'}}
{$obj->{'0a'}}
EOT;
```

Exemplo [online no IDEONE](https://ideone.com/weKC34)